# How to connect eth0 with docker custom network

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose

The big picture: I need to build an automatic testing environment which will allow me to test port scanning tools.

This is github repo which I am using as a playground: https://github.com/WojciechMigda/tested-scanners

What I have:

- two (there will be more) containers running `snmpd`, connected to a custom ipv4 & ipv6 network `net-snmpd`, connected to `br-snmpd` host interface.
- I can `ping` and `ping6` a container from the host.
- `nmap` can perform sanity scan of port 161, both over ipv4 and ipv6 network. Note: `nmap` operates on IP layer level. It sends IP probe packets to `br-snmpd` interface.

The problem:

I am also running `masscan` to perfom a port scan. In contrast to `nmap` `masscan` operates on ethernet layer. By default, when interface is not explicitly specified, `masscan` uses host's eth0 interface. This interface is selected because default route leads to it. Unfortunately, `masscan` fails to detect open port on the container.

However, `masscan` can be also run by specifying a network interface (`br-snmpd` instead of `eth0`) and associated router's MAC. With such settings `masscan` succeeds with port detection on the container.

I tried changing different things but I am not able to find the missing piece - what needs to be additionally configured to allow `masscan` to successfully scan port on a container through `eth0` interface?

Another setting which I would like to achieve is to have a router (gateway?) associated with `br-snmpd`, so that when `br-snmpd` is selected as working interface for `masscan` then it will attempt router MAC discovery for a non-null router ip address.

`docker-compose.yml`: https://github.com/WojciechMigda/tested-scanners/blob/main/tests/resources/docker-compose.yml

github actions workflow: https://github.com/WojciechMigda/tested-scanners/blob/main/.github/workflows/test.yml

One of workflow runs: https://github.com/WojciechMigda/tested-scanners/actions/runs/4813378705/jobs/8569841427

```
  ip -4 addr
  ip -6 addr

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 10.1.24.5/16 metric 100 brd 10.1.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: br-snmpd: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    inet 10.9.0.1/24 brd 10.9.0.255 scope global br-snmpd
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::6245:bdff:fe7a:4922/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 state DOWN 
    inet6 2001:db8:1::1/64 scope global tentative 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1/64 scope link tentative 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: br-snmpd: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP 
    inet6 2001:db8:1:1::1/120 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:31ff:fed7:61d3/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: veth58fff89@if5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP 
    inet6 fe80::14f4:fcff:fe3c:2b8a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: veth55e96c9@if7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP 
    inet6 fe80::d471:a4ff:febf:8273/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
  ip -4 route
  ip -6 route

default via 10.1.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.1.24.5 metric 100 
10.1.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.24.5 metric 100 
10.1.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.1.24.5 metric 100 
10.9.0.0/24 dev br-snmpd proto kernel scope link src 10.9.0.1 
168.63.129.16 via 10.1.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.1.24.5 metric 100 
169.254.169.254 via 10.1.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.1.24.5 metric 100 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2001:db8:1::/64 dev docker0 proto kernel metric 256 linkdown pref medium
2001:db8:1::/64 dev docker0 metric 1024 linkdown pref medium
2001:db8:1:1::/120 dev br-snmpd proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev docker0 proto kernel metric 256 linkdown pref medium
fe80::/64 dev br-snmpd proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth58fff89 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth55e96c9 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that by design traffic from `eth0` into containers is disabled.

Moreover, after a while I realized that much more convenient and better solution will involve running scanners inside a container, and then having scan targets running either in LAN containter or in containers running in separate network connected through peered `bird` routers.